# Написать формулу Эйлера по-простому

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input("Введите число: "))
k = 0 #проверка
b=[] #массив, чтобы делить каждое число до n
cnt=0 #счётчик простых чисел
for j in range(2,n+1):
    b.append(j) #заполнение массива числами
for a in b:
    for i in range(2, (a//2)+1): #проверка на простоту
        if (a % i == 0):
            print(a,i)
            k = k+1
    if (k <= 0):
        cnt+=1 #если простое + к счётчику
print(cnt) #вывод
```

Почему-то не хочет считать простые числа после 3. Хотелось бы помощи. Я специально решил вывести числа, которые не подходят (то есть являются непростыми) с их делителями. Пример на картинке показывает, что числа 5 и 7 по какой-то причине программа не затрагивает.

Comment: ``if (k <= 0)`` это что?

Comment: @Эникейщик Если k будет больше 0, значит число делится ровно на какое-то ещё кроме себя и единицы, поэтому if k<=0 мы прибавляем к счётчику простых чисел +1

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не так происходит? ... что значит не хочет считать? ... Более развернуто распишите ваши ожидания и ошибку.

Comment: @Volk я внёс правки

Comment: В проверке написано, что k должно быть 0 или меньше 0, а не больше единицы.

Comment: @Эникейщик Такое условие. k - считает сколько есть делителей у числа кроме самого себя и единицы.

Comment: Перенесите обнуление k = 0 в начало цикла for a in b:

Comment: @MBo Огромное спасибо! Помогло. Но не знаю как выделить ваш комментарий правильным ответом 

Comment: @Kvinkel Сделал ответом

Answer (score 3):

```
for a in b:
    k = 0 # обнуляем счётчик для каждого числа
    for i in range(2, (a//2)+1): #проверка на простоту
```